# Asterisk VOIP server monitor

Tags: voip, asterisk

I am Working with Asterisk VOIP servers.
I want a system that monitors all servers and tell me when someone has a problem, such as: no ssh access, no internet, no authentication with a sip trunk.

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will want to look at [Nagios](http://www.nagios.com/). There are plugins available for Asterisk.

Comment: Use nagios + snmp on asterisk.